# How to decode character pressed from jQuery's keydown()'s event handler

Tags: jquery, event-handling, character, keydown

I need to figure out which character was typed into a text field from within the handler that is called by jQuery's `keydown` function. `key.which` gives me only the keycode, but I need to figure out which ASCII character `key` represents. How do I do this?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

For character input, it is suggested you use `keypress()`, which will report the actual ASCII code for the character pressed. It automatically takes care of letter case, and ignores non-character presses. In either case, you can use fromCharCode() to convert to a string representation. E.g.

```
var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which) // or e.keyCode
```

Just remember that for `keydown()` and `keyup()`, you'll have to keep track of the case using the `e.shiftKey` state.

Comment: haha.. for some reason, browsers are returning 188 when comma is pressed, but when we convert 188 to char, it is coming as ¼. Interestingly, when we convert 44 to char, browsers are understanding it as comma!!

Comment: I believe it return 1/4 in old version of jQuery. In 1.4.2 it's fixed. It return comma for me

Comment: hmm this does not account for e.shiftKey

Comment: I vote for keypress - it receives correct characters for international keyboard layouts, unlike keydown which converts everything to single byte characters.

Comment: Oh, so `String` is not a var... :((

Comment: e.which returns the Id of the key, not the character.

Answer (score 110):

The `keyPress` event is what you need to get which character was entered. (*See below workaround for keydown event*).

`keydown` and `keyup` provide a code indicating which key is pressed, while `keypress` indicates which character was entered.

Using jQuery `e.which` you can get the key code and using [**String.fromCharCode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) you can get the specific character that was pressed (including <kbd>shiftKey</kbd>).

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9TyzP/3

**Code:**

```
element.on ('keypress', function (e) {
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
})
```

> Note I said jQuery's `e.which` because different browsers use differing properties to store this information. jQuery normalizes the `.which` property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the key code.

**Workaround for `keydown`**

However you can write a simple workaround to get the pressed character working on `keydown`.. The workaround is to create an object with key as the charCode without shift keypress and the value is with shift key.

Note: As [@Sajjan Sarkar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220196/how-to-decode-character-pressed-from-jquerys-keydowns-event-handler/13127566#comment17968387_13127566) pointed out there are some differences in `e.which` keycode value returned from different browser. [**Read more here**](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)

Updated the DEMO code to normalize the cross browser keyCode value. Tested and verified in IE 8, FF and Chrome.

**Full Code below and updated DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/S2dyB/17/

```
$(function() {

    var _to_ascii = {
        '188': '44',
        '109': '45',
        '190': '46',
        '191': '47',
        '192': '96',
        '220': '92',
        '222': '39',
        '221': '93',
        '219': '91',
        '173': '45',
        '187': '61', //IE Key codes
        '186': '59', //IE Key codes
        '189': '45'  //IE Key codes
    }

    var shiftUps = {
        "96": "~",
        "49": "!",
        "50": "@",
        "51": "#",
        "52": "$",
        "53": "%",
        "54": "^",
        "55": "&",
        "56": "*",
        "57": "(",
        "48": ")",
        "45": "_",
        "61": "+",
        "91": "{",
        "93": "}",
        "92": "|",
        "59": ":",
        "39": "\"",
        "44": "<",
        "46": ">",
        "47": "?"
    };

    $(element).on('keydown', function(e) {
        var c = e.which;

        //normalize keyCode 
        if (_to_ascii.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
            c = _to_ascii[c];
        }

        if (!e.shiftKey && (c >= 65 && c <= 90)) {
            c = String.fromCharCode(c + 32);
        } else if (e.shiftKey && shiftUps.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
            //get shifted keyCode value
            c = shiftUps[c];
        } else {
            c = String.fromCharCode(c);
        }

        //$(element).val(c);
    }).on('keypress', function(e) {
        //$(element).val(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    });    
});
```

More about keyboard events --

The keydown, keypress and keyup events fire when the user presses a key.

**keydown** Fires when the user depresses a key. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.

**keypress** Fires when an actual character is being inserted in, for instance, a text input. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.

**keyup** Fires when the user releases a key, after the default action of that key has been performed.

When a key is first depressed, the `keydown` event is sent. If the key is not a modifier key, the `keypress` event is sent. When the user releases the key, the `keyup` event is sent.

When a key is pressed and held down, it begins to auto-repeat. This results in a sequence of events similar to the following being dispatched:

```
keydown
keypress
keydown
keypress
<<repeating until the user releases the key>>
keyup
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9TyzP/1/

**keyup, keydown vs keypress**

The keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released, while the keypress event represents a character being typed.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9TyzP/

**References:**

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent
2. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html
3. http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: this looks like a great canonical answer, will wait a few days so this gets a bit more exposure before awarding

Comment: Yes, but as "the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms."
src:http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

AFAIK, you cannot get the ASCII value in keydown, you can only get it in keyup or keypress as the above person pointed out.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar Not true.. You get the `keyCode` (e.which) on `keydown/keyup/keypress`. If you want the ASCII character then you can use `String.fromCharCode` function. You don't get the character in `keyup/keypress`.

Comment: @Vega Yes and no, try saying Console.log(String.fromCharCode(e.which)) and see what u get for semi-colon and colon.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar That is because control keys are passed as `e.shiftKey` on `keydown` and the value is returned as without `shift`. That was the original issue in this bounty question to begin with. Also I have mentioned that clearly in my alternate solution with a demo http://jsfiddle.net/S2dyB/4/

Comment: @Vega its a nice approach, but the truth is, when I press colon (shift+;) i expect the code to give me ":" not "º:" But ur answer is still the best one around..

Comment: @SajjanSarkar Which browser are you getting that result `º:`?

Comment: @SajjanSarkar Thanks and that was a good catch.. I did some readings and based on which I have normalized the keycode so that it works across browser. Updated DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/S2dyB/14/

Comment: @Vega except now it gives "::" when I type ":".. same with semi-colons

Comment: @SajjanSarkar The DEMO was to demonstrate the keydown keyCode handler and as per the demo you are supposed to keydown outside the textbox. Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/S2dyB/17/

Answer (score 1):

I do this. It will just ignore the keypress if the value is not a number.
Seems to work without any problems...

```
    $("input").on("keypress", function(e) {
        if(!jQuery.isNumeric(String.fromCharCode(e.which)))
            return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Selvakumar Arumugam's answer works like a charm for me...until I test numpad. So a minor update here:

```
 $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    var c = e.which;

    if (_to_ascii.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
        c = _to_ascii[c];
    }

    if (!e.shiftKey && (c >= 65 && c <= 90)) {
        c = String.fromCharCode(c + 32);
    } else if (e.shiftKey && shiftUps.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
        c = shiftUps[c];
    } else if (96 <= c && c <= 105) {
        c = String.fromCharCode(c - 48);
    }else {
        c = String.fromCharCode(c);
    }

    $kd.val(c);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S2dyB/78/

Answer (score 0):

I created and use the above javascript class for converting gr to en characters. It is able to be used for more languages. It uses JQuery for changing the value pressed from user.

```
var CharMapper = function (selector) {
    this.getLanguageMapper = function (languageSource, languageTarget) {
        // Check if the map is already defined.
        if (typeof langugageCharMap === "undefined") {
            langugageCharMap = {};
        }
        if (typeof langugageCharMap[languageSource] === "undefined") {
            langugageCharMap[languageSource] = {};
        }

        // Initialize or get the language mapper.
        if (typeof langugageCharMap[languageSource][languageTarget] === "undefined") {
            switch (languageSource) {
                case "GR":
                    switch (languageTarget) {
                        case "EN":
                            langugageCharMap[languageSource][languageTarget] = {
                                "α": "a", "ά": "a", "β": "b", "γ": "g", "δ": "d", "ε": "e", "έ": "e", "ζ": "z", "η": "h", "ή": "h", "θ": "th", "ι": "i", "ί": "i", "ϊ": "i", "ΐ": "i", "κ": "k", "λ": "l", "μ": "m", "ν": "n", "ξ": "ks", "ο": "o", "ό": "o", "π": "p", "ρ": "r", "σ": "s", "ς": "s", "τ": "t", "υ": "y", "ύ": "y", "ϋ": "y", "ΰ": "y", "φ": "f", "χ": "x", "ψ": "ps", "ω": "o", "ώ": "o", "Α": "A", "Ά": "A", "Β": "B", "Γ": "G", "Δ": "D", "Ε": "E", "Έ": "E", "Ζ": "Z", "Η": "H", "Ή": "H", "Θ": "TH", "Ι": "I", "Ί": "I", "Ϊ": "I", "Κ": "K", "Λ": "L", "Μ": "M", "Ν": "N", "Ξ": "KS", "Ο": "O", "Ό": "O", "Π": "P", "Ρ": "R", "Σ": "S", "Τ": "T", "Υ": "Y", "Ύ": "Y", "Ϋ": "Y", "Φ": "F", "Χ": "X", "Ψ": "PS", "Ω": "O", "Ώ": "O"
                            };
                            break;
                        case "GR":
                        default:
                            throw "Language(" + languageTarget + ") is not supported as target for Language(" + languageSource + ").";
                    }
                    break;
                case "EN":
                default:
                    throw "Language(" + languageSource + ") is not supported as source.";
            }
        }

        return langugageCharMap[languageSource][languageTarget];
    };
    // Check the existance of the attribute.
    var items = $(selector).find("*[data-mapkey]");
    if (items.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // For each item.
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];

        // Get the source and target language.
        var languages = $(item).attr("data-mapkey");
        var languageSource = languages.split("_")[0];
        var languageTarget = languages.split("_")[1];

        // Add the event listener.
        var self = this;
        $(item).keypress(function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            // Get the mapper to use.
            var mapper = self.getLanguageMapper(languageSource, languageTarget);
            // Get the key pressed.
            var keyPressed = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
            // Get the key to set. In case it doesn't exist in the mapper, get the key pressed.
            var keyToSet = mapper[keyPressed] || keyPressed;
            // Set the key to the dom.
            this.value = this.value + keyToSet;

            // Do not propagate.
            return false;
        });
    }
};
```

Example,

```
<input type="text" data-mapkey="GR_EN" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    new CharMapper("body");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**keypress is deprecated, you should use keydown instead**

Use .key - to get the keypress

The syntax is:

```
$(selector).keydown(function(event) {
  console.log(event.key)
})
```

Example:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  // print out each keypress
  console.log(event.key)
})
```