# String.fromCharCode(e.which) doesn't recognize dot and comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have created a function for input mask with jQuery:

```
$.fn.mask = function(regex) { 
    this.on("keydown keyup", function(e) {
        if (regex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

It denies any input based on the regex you pass. Examples:

```
$("#textfield").mask(/\s/); // denies white spaces
$("#textfield").mask(/\D/); // denies anything but numbers
```

Those examples above works, but I'm trying to use a regex to accept numbers with decimal separator, like this:

```
$("#textfield").mask(/[^\d.,]/); // Anything except digits, dot and comma
```

That doesn't work. But if I log `String.fromCharCode(e.which)` on console when I press `.` or `,` it shows me these(respective) chars: `¾` and `¼`.

The question is why `String.fromCharCode(e.which)` stands for those chars instead of the pressed ones?

Comment: The keycode you get from those events is a **key** code, not a character code.

Comment: @Pointy Forgive my ignorance but I don't got the difference.

Comment: You are trying to get unicode characters from a key code, which only works in `keypress` handlers (not `keydown` or `keyup`). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444477/keycode-and-charcode) for more info.

Comment: The value identifies which key on the keyboard was pressed. Consider the "6" key - the code identifies the key, but that same key might result in a "6" or a "^".  It's just a different concept.

Comment: Following up on @Pointy's comment, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5829387/901048) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13127566/901048) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to deal with actual characters produced from keyboard, not a layout position of a key.

```
$.fn.mask = function(regex) { 
    this.on("keypress", function(e) {
        if (regex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

The `keypress` event reports the code point of a character produced.

http://jsfiddle.net/USgNJ/

Comment: Yes, I have got this solution. Just waited for someone to post it to mark as right answer. Thank you.