# How do I enable arrow navigation on keyboard for a list of Div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, tagging, arrow-keys

I am following a tutorial [here][1] to make a Facebook like friend tagging system. But the tutorial lacks the "arrow navigating" capability like Facebook. I would like to figure out how to achieve this.

Basically, when I input text on the contenteditable area, it will generate divs of suggested friends like the following:

```
<div class="display_box">    
   <img src="user_img/John.jpg">
   <a href="#" class="addname" title="John">John</a><br>
   <span>India</span>
</div>
<div class="display_box">    
   <img src="user_img/Peter.jpg">
   <a href="#" class="addname" title="Peter">Peter</a><br>
   <span>USA</span>
</div>
<div class="display_box">    
   <img src="user_img/Mary.jpg>
   <a href="#" class="addname" title="Mary">Mary</a><br>
   <span>UK</span>
</div>
```

They are all divs with the class name `display_box`. I can click on the box and select them by:

```
$('div').on("click",".display_box",function(e) {
    // do the stuffs
});
```

I would like my users to be able to use the keyboard, using key up or key down to navigate between the selections, and use the enter key to trigger the selection. Any ideas how can I make this happen? Many thanks!

Comment: It is actually the same, but you don't use click but keypress or keyup or keydown, which suits the best. If you want continuous scrolling when the user presses but doesn't release the arrow key use for example keydown. The next step would be to pass other argument inside the function. Have a look at this answer to find out the key code [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220196/how-to-decode-character-pressed-from-jquerys-keydowns-event-handler] and then google for a table of characters to know which key was pressed. GL with your project!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bind keyboard events `keyup/keydown` and then change the css accordingly to give a feel of `move up` or `move down` :

use `keyup` if you want a single move even on a key press no matter the key is long pressed.

use `keydown` if you want to move in a cycle fashion as long as user holds the key.

```
$("#search").keyup(function(e) 
{
        if (e.keyCode == 40) 
        {  
            Navigate(1);
        }
        if(e.keyCode==38)
        {
            Navigate(-1);
        }

});
```

Check complete code @fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MKZSE/77/