# Horizontal and Vertical navigation inside div using arrows along and down the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML **div** with multi line(more than one line) of text. I need to enable horizontal and vertical navigation using keyboard arrows(**up, down, left , right**) as in html input fields(text-area, text) along the text or down the next lines.

```
<div id='enabled_arrow_navigation'>
 Horizontal and Vertical navigation inside, div using arrows along and down the text, 
 Horizontal and Vertical navigation inside div using arrows along and down the text
 Horizontal and Vertical navigation inside div using arrows along and down the text
</div>
```

I tried bellow code but its not working

```
$("#enabled_arrow_navigation").keyup(function(e) 
{
    if (e.keyCode == 40) 
    {  
        Navigate(1);
    }
    if(e.keyCode==38)
    {
        Navigate(-1);
    }
});
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: what did you tried?

Comment: @Raj I updated question desc

Comment: @ALOK I tried this on div but did not worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147266/how-do-i-enable-arrow-navigation-on-keyboard-for-a-list-of-div-using-jquery

Comment: that is contenteditable div.  What did you tried? share some code

Comment: @ALOK   updated with code I tried in question description

Comment: you need to make your div editable, something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Ljyrrafd/

Comment: @ALOK this is exactly  I am looking for thanks. you can answer the question and I will mark it as correct so that other can make use of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a div editable by adding contenteditable attribute to true

```html
<div id='enabled_arrow_navigation' contenteditable='true'>
 Horizontal and Vertical navigation inside, div using arrows along and down the text, 
 Horizontal and Vertical navigation inside div using arrows along and down the text
 Horizontal and Vertical navigation inside div using arrows along and down the text
</div>
```