# String.fromCharCode on keypress and keydown are returning wrong characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode, utf-8, keycode

I'm trying to catch the character inserted before it shows on the screen to validate the screen. See my code

```
_this.on('keypress keydown',function(e){
    var t = e.target;
    var k = e.which || e.keyCode;
    var c = String.fromCharCode(k);
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(k))
});
```

If I for example type `~` or any other punctuation characters, it returns non-latin characters, such as `å`. I'm on Chromium, Ubuntu.

I noticed that the keypress is being ignored with these special characters, what is a shame and that's why I am trying with keydown as well. But keydown fails to detect the right character and converts them to scandinavian and asian characters.

Is there a workaround to get the correct character being yped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13127566/5090789) to a similar question, and the associated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S2dyB/17/

One problem is that the `keypress` and `keydown` events are not interchangeable.  `keypress` is used to retrieve the actual character that was typed (so special keys are ignored), while `keydown` returns a unique character code for each key on the keyboard.  To exacerbate this, different browsers handle each event a little bit differently, making it a big mess.

Take a look at how `e.which` varies between `keydown` and `keypress`: http://jsfiddle.net/9TyzP/

As you can see, they rarely match up--and with many keys, the displayed code for `keypress` doesn't change at all, indicating that the event did not fire for that key.